# excel fill series restart from 1 after new value

Tags: excel, fill, series

I have the following in one column, it keeps going down with random letters but always end with 1.

a1
a1
b1
b1
b1
b1
b1
c1
c1
c1

how can i make it fill series but start again from one when ever a new letter.

It should look like this:

a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
b4
b5
c1
c2
c3

Answer (score 0):

You can genereate a new series in the column beside it.  Lets assume your data starts in A1.  In put 1 in B1 and in B2 place the following:

```
=IF(left(A1,len(A1)-1)=left(A2,len(A2)-1),B1+1,1)
```

Copy B2 down.

When you are done, you can copy your information from column B and paste is a values if you do not want the numbers changing again.